# How to get the name of all projects in a TFS collection?

Tags: c#, tfs, alm

On how to get the collections from TFS refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100991/how-to-get-all-collections-from-tfs/16100992#16100992)

Please refer [here](http://blog.johnsworkshop.net/) for more details. This is one of the best resources on TFS stuff.

Answer (score 3):

The collection guid is passed in and the list returns the name of all projects in that particular collection.

```
    public IList<string> GetProjectsFormCollection(Guid collectionId)
{
    ICommonStructureService structureService = null;
    try
    {
        TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection =
            _configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId);
        teamProjectCollection.Authenticate();
        structureService =
            (ICommonStructureService)teamProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(ICommonStructureService));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ApplicationLogger.Log(e);
    }

    var projectInfoList = new List<ProjectInfo>(structureService.ListAllProjects());
    IEnumerable<string> data = projectInfoList.Select(proj => proj.Name);
    List<string> list = data.ToList();
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Whats the <ProjectInfo> object you have here ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this now via the rest api. e.g.

```
GET https://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0
```

from: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects