# How to get build definitions from TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs, alm

How to get build definitions using TFS-API given [collection-guid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100991/how-to-get-all-collections-from-tfs/16100992#16100992) and [project-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101636/how-to-get-the-name-of-all-projects-in-a-tfs-collection/16101637#16101637)

Please refer [here](http://blog.johnsworkshop.net/) for more details. This is one of the best resources on TFS stuff.

Answer (score 9):

```
private TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer;  

configurationServer = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(uri);



public IList<KeyValuePair<string, Uri>> GetBuildDefinitionListFromProject(Guid collectionId, string projectName)
{
    List<IBuildDefinition> buildDefinitionList = null;
    List<KeyValuePair<string, Uri>> buildDefinitionInfoList = null;

    try
    {
        buildDefinitionInfoList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, Uri>>();
        TfsTeamProjectCollection tfsProjectCollection =
        configurationServer.GetTeamProjectCollection(collectionId);
        tfsProjectCollection.Authenticate();
        var buildServer = (IBuildServer)tfsProjectCollection.GetService(typeof(IBuildServer));
        buildDefinitionList = new List<IBuildDefinition>(buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions(projectName));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ApplicationLogger.Log(e);
    }

    if (buildDefinitionList != null && buildDefinitionList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (IBuildDefinition builddef in buildDefinitionList)
        {
            buildDefinitionInfoList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Uri>(builddef.Name, builddef.Uri));
        }
    }
    return buildDefinitionInfoList;
}
```

Comment: What about TFS 2015 vNext builds?