# TFS 2015. Get CollectionName by item

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have next situation and I am stack.

I am using Microsoft.TeamFoundation classes to get workitems from stored query with c#. I know server name, project name and stored query name. So I can execute stored query and receive all WorkItems.

But than I have to create a direct link to this item. According to the documentation, this link should be like

```
http:// ServerName:8080/tfs/CollectionName/ProjectName/_workitems/edit/Id
```

So, before executing query I know ServerName, ProjectName and work item's Id. But I cant find ProjectName anywhere.

So my question is. How, knowing ServerName, ProjectName, WorkItemId and Stored Query name get CollectionName?

Or. How to create link to the work item knowing ItemsId?

P.S. GetArtifactUrl is not the right way.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Which url do you usually use when browsing to see the workitems when you are normaly working with this team project (hint look at that ur) ? Or are you trying to create something that searches in all Team Project Collections ?

Comment: You're question can be interpreted in at least 3 ways. Are you trying this on a on-prem TFS server or on Visual Studio Team Services ?

Comment: I am using on-prem TFS server

Comment: Rolf Huisman I know my URL and I can extract data from here. But question is not about this. I need to extract data from Project + Stored query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afraid there is no such API to achieve this. However, as a workaround, you can list all  collection's name through client API such as below:

```
        Uri configurationServerUri = new Uri(URL);
      TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer = TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(configurationServerUri);
                                    ITeamProjectCollectionService tpcService = configurationServer.GetService<ITeamProjectCollectionService>();

    foreach (TeamProjectCollection tpc in tpcService.GetCollections())
                                {
                                    ListCollection.Add(tpc.Name);
                                }
```

More ways for your reference:

- [How to get all collections from TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16100991/how-to-get-all-collections-from-tfs)
- [Retrieve the List of Team Project Collections from TFS 2010 Client APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/taylaf/2010/01/26/retrieve-the-list-of-team-project-collections-from-tfs-2010-client-apis/)

Comment: This solution requires another lvl of access rights. Any other idea?

Comment: Maybe you could try to find it through TFS database.

Comment: @Patrick: wouldn't that require to traverse multiple databases, since a tpc is linked to a databases ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. A collection ,a database. You may traverse multiple databases. The solution I suggest in the answer should be a better one.